# How to sync location when app is in background

Tags: ios, swift, timer, background, location

I want to send user current `Location` to a server in every 15 minutes. When the app is in the foreground the `timer` is running but when the app is in background timer is not running. I searched a lot but did not find any solution. Can you please tell me what I do. I am using below code for background location sync but it's not working.

```
    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var currentLocation: CLLocation?
    var timer : Timer?
    var backgroundTaskIdentifier: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier?

   func getCurrentLocation()
    {
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
        locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
        //
        backgroundTaskIdentifier = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler: {
            UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(self.backgroundTaskIdentifier!)
        })
        let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 10.0, repeats: true) { (timer) in
            self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
    {
        print("locations = \(locations)")
        if  let location = locations.last
        {
            print("location\(String(describing: location.coordinate))")
            currentLocation = location
            locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Make sure that: 1- "Location Updates" option in the Capabilities of your project is selected. 2- Your app is allowed to detect to detect the location (perrmission from the iOS).

Comment: Also look into `significantLocationChangeMonitoringAvailable`. See if that helps better since you will be draining battery with your location manager calls.

Comment: @adev he already did... please check the code!

Comment: @AhmadF, thanks, I missed that somehow.

Comment: Its working only 3 minutes when  start timer every 60 seconds and then it stop working

Comment: @AhmadF I already done this

Answer (score 0):

I am also having similar kind of requirement but time interval is 5minutes.

May be your app in idle for longer time(15 minutes) that's y OS is not updating your locations.

Try to keep shorter interval and try it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Did you handle location update from `AppDelegate` for application state? If not you can update your code with below methods in `AppDelegate`.

```
var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

func doBackgroundTask() {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        self.beginBackgroundUpdateTask()
        self.StartupdateLocation()
        RunLoop.current.run()
    }
}

func beginBackgroundUpdateTask() {
    backgroundUpdateTask = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler: {
        self.endBackgroundUpdateTask()
    })
}
func endBackgroundUpdateTask() {
    UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(self.backgroundUpdateTask)
    self.backgroundUpdateTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
}

func StartupdateLocation() {
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
    locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
}
```

Call the method when application is going in background state.

```
func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    self.doBackgroundTask()
}
```

This methods will help you for getting update of location when app is in background.
You can take a look at this link if you face any other difficulties. [Update location in Background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47300435/update-location-in-background)

Comment: How many hours can I get the user location in the background?

Comment: As long as your app is in background.

Comment: I have tried this method but its works only 20 min. after that background syncing automatically stops