# Getting location with app closed - SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, location, background-process

I'm making an app that updates the user's location from time to time, and I need to know if it's possible to keep getting the location and sending it to the API even if the user closes the app (really closes, not just switch to other page). I'm searching for this answer for a long time now, can someone help me?

Comment: Try “significant change in location”

Comment: This is a similar question [Update location in Background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47300435/update-location-in-background)